# Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, air-native-extension, filestreams

Good Day,
I working in Android/IOS  App using AIR 3.5. 
In this project I download ZIP file and extracted in specific folder, after that I using the assets ( IMG, XML and Sounds), everything work fine but when I load the sounds it's keep show this error.
**> Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.**
I tried to give it static location in android drive but same error happened.
I tried to use URLRequest, FileStream, URLStream and same thing happened.
I traced all files bath in the folder and it's give me all the baths correct.
This is the code.

```
trace('AliSoundFile/' + ob.sound);          
var soundFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('AliSoundFile/'+ob.sound);
var files:Array = soundFile.getDirectoryListing();
            trace((File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('AliSoundFile/'+ob.sound).nativePath) );
//sound = new Sound( new URLRequest ('AliSoundFile/1.mp3'));
sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, sound_ioError);
for ( var i:uint = 0 ; i < files.length ; i++)
{
      if (files[i].isDirectory )
    {
       var arr:Array = files[i].getDirectoryListing();
        for ( var j:uint = 0 ;  j <  arr.length ; j++)
        trace('J:-> ',arr[j].nativePath);
    }
    trace('I:-> ',files[i].nativePath);
}
soundStreen = new FileStream();
soundStreen.openAsync(soundFile, FileMode.READ);
soundStreen.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, soundStreen_complete); 
soundStreen.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, soundStreen_ioError); 
trace('end');
    private function soundStreen_complete(e:Event):void 
    {
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
        soundStreen.readBytes( ba );
        _loadSound = new Loader();
        _loadSound.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, soundLoadbytesComplete );
        _loadSound.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadSound_progress);
        _loadSound.loadBytes( ba );
    }

    private function soundLoadbytesComplete(e:Event):void 
    {
        sound.play();
        sound = e.currentTarget.content as Sound;
        soundStreen.close();
    }
```

Anyone can help me with this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: To handle this unhandled exceptions add addEventListener for  IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR to contentLoaderInfo
Second: Loader class is used to load SWF files or image (JPG, PNG, or GIF) files ( see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html ) so the problem is in that you pass invalid stream (Sound streem ).
To play a file check this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d25.html

Comment: Thank you, I used the IOError handle, and its don't give me an error??!                                   soundStreen.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, soundStreen_ioError);                                                         private function soundStreen_ioError(e:IOErrorEvent):void 
{trace("An Error Occured and it looked like this.", e.text);}, and I used the the loader to load the bytes             soundStreen.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, soundStreen_ioError); I see your links now, thank you :)

Comment: The IOError is rised from loadBytes from _loadSound not from soundStreem

Comment: Hello 
I solve it :), By using this article 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033442/as3-android-saving-remote-sounds-on-sdcard-accessing-later

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar 2032 issues, and was discovered due to Apache 2.4 upgrade.  We have since rolled back the Apache and all is well!

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error even though I was handling the IOErrorEvent... or so I thought but it turned out that a HTTPStatusEvent (500 in my case) was being triggered before the IOError event and I was removing the event listeners in my HTTPStatusEvent handler before the IOError event.  Derp!